# For unknown reason "if" works when the condition is zero

Tags: c

The "if" always goes through the first one, even though it is zero most of the time. I am not sure why, and it does these only when startr is big enough, on smaller startr it works good

Also, the purpose of the code is to find local minimum of the function

```
const double delta = 0.0000001, eps = 0.000001;

int power(int i, int n)
{
   int out = 1;
   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
   {
      out *= i;
   }

   return out;
}

double f(double u)
{
    return ((u * u - 3) / (u + 1));
}

int main()
{
    double l = 0, r = 0, startl = -2, startr = 15;
    int k = 0, pow = 0;
    double ll = 0, rr = 0;
    double savl = 0, savr = 0;

    l = startl;
    r = startr;
    do
    {
        ll = (l + r - delta) / 2;
        rr = (l + r + delta) / 2;

        savl = f(ll);
        savr = f(rr);

        if (savl * savl > savr * savr) r = rr; 
        if (savl * savl < savr * savr) l = ll;

        k++;
        pow = power(2, k);
    }
    while (((startr - startl) / pow + (1 - 1 / pow) * delta) > eps);

    printf("%f ", (ll + rr) / 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I have edited the code, so all the functions would be visible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), with special concentration on 'complete'.  You call a function `f()`; you don't show it. Ditto for `power()`.  Ditto variables `eps`, `delta`. That makes it hard for us.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt update adding the missing information.  That's most helpful.  So often, the person asking goes off for an hour or two after asking their question, and doesn't update it, and … well, it doesn't help it get answered.  You did right by being responsive.

Comment: I have tried and the same problem appears. It moves the left point, even though it should move the right one as the condition says

Comment: The problem I see when I put `printf("l = %10.6f, r = %10.6f, ll = %10.6f, rr = %10.6f, d = %10.6f, savl = %10.6f, savr = %10.6f\n",
              l, r, ll, rr, delta, savl, savr);` between the two calls to `f()` and the `if` tests is that the values of `ll` and `rr` are the same to 6 decimal places, so `savl` and `savr` are the same to 6 decimal places too.  I probably need to change the format to something like `%22.14e` instead, but that requires a really wide window for readability (this output requires about 120 characters; that requires 202 characters or more).

Comment: I have found that comparison marks have to be swapped in order to find the minimal value. It was the initial mistake

Comment: Are you trying to find (one of) the roots of the equation (x²-3)÷(x+1)?  Which algorithm are you trying to implement.  It isn't Newton-Raphson; it might be some sort of binary search, but I'm not sure that it is implemented correctly.  The `do { … } while (…)` condition is puzzling, since it uses `startr` and `startl` (which don't change).  Should it be using `l` and `r` instead?

Comment: I am searching for the local minimum, and it is a binary search, yes

Comment: And the code is searching for roots. For finding minimum, f should be the derivative of the function. Thank everyone for the help!

Comment: You have a discontinuity at u = -1 because then you divide by 0.  That's going to be fun if you ever evaluate `f()` with -1.0.  I need to graph it — especially around -1.

Comment: `printf("%.15f\n", savr*savr - savl*savl);` before the `if` statements show the gap increases.

Comment: Yes, there also should be 2 in the divider

Comment: FYI, you should use `else if` for mutually-exclusive conditions. Or just use `else` if the second condition is the opposite of the first condition. Note that you don't do anything in the case where `savl * savl == savr * savr`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const double delta = 0.0000000001, eps = 0.000001;

int power(int i, int n)
{
    int out = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        out *= i;
    }

    return out;
}

double f(double u)
{
    return ((u * u + 2 * u + 3) / (u + 2) / (u + 2));  //derivative of the f
}

int main()
{
    double l = 0, r = 0, startl = -2, startr = 15;
    int k = 0, pow = 0;
    double ll = 0, rr = 0;
    double savl = 0, savr = 0;

    l = startl;
    r = startr;
    do
    {
        ll = (l + r - delta) / 2;
        rr = (l + r + delta) / 2;

        savl = f(ll);
        savr = f(rr);

        if (savl * savl < savr * savr) r = rr; //printf("%f %f %e\n", savl, savr, savl * savl - savr * savr);
        if (savl * savl > savr * savr) l = ll;

        k++;
        pow = power(2, k);
    }
    while (((startr - startl) / pow + (1 - 1 / pow) * delta) > eps);

    printf("%f ", (ll + rr) / 2);

    return 0;
}
```

working code
The problem was in wrong comparison marks at ifs and the fact that I was searching for the fuction's root instead of it's derivative's

Comment: Don't just dump working code. Explain what his problem was, and how you solved it. Everyone shouldn't have to search for the differences to figure out what you fixed.

Comment: Code cheats here.  The premise is that `f()` is given, yet this code "knows" the derivative of `f()` and then confusingly calls it `f()`.  A better solution would use the original `f()` and devise a good result.

Comment: `if (savl * savl < savr * savr)` is a convoluted and less precise way of testing `if (fabs(savl) < fabs(savr))`.